# Cannot connect to MS services across networks

Tags: windows, network-share

So we've got two offices connected via Sonicwall IKE VPN:

- HQ is 10.42.0.0/16
- Remote is 10.63.0.0/16

There is an MS file share on a Windows 7 Pro box in HQ, 10.42.3.203, and machines in the Remote office need to access it. Both firewalls have 'allow any to any' rules for traffic between the two networks, and no deny rules that would apply to the traffic.

Below is a tshark transcript of someone in the remote office attempting to access the share in HQ. The machine running it listens on a mirrored uplink port behind the HQ firewall.

```
414.411940   10.63.3.39 -> 10.42.3.203  TCP 66 55628 > microsoft-ds [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1398 WS=256 SACK
415.518100   10.63.3.39 -> 10.42.3.203  TCP 66 55635 > microsoft-ds [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1398 WS=256 SACK
415.519325   10.63.3.39 -> 10.42.3.203  TCP 66 55636 > netbios-ssn [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1398 WS=256 SACK_
417.429670   10.63.3.39 -> 10.42.3.203  TCP 66 [TCP Retransmission] 55628 > microsoft-ds [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0
418.516965   10.63.3.39 -> 10.42.3.203  TCP 66 [TCP Retransmission] 55636 > netbios-ssn [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0
418.516969   10.63.3.39 -> 10.42.3.203  TCP 66 [TCP Retransmission] 55635 > microsoft-ds [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0
423.421594   10.63.3.39 -> 10.42.3.203  TCP 62 [TCP Retransmission] 55628 > microsoft-ds [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=
424.525998   10.63.3.39 -> 10.42.3.203  TCP 62 [TCP Retransmission] 55636 > netbios-ssn [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0
424.526002   10.63.3.39 -> 10.42.3.203  TCP 62 [TCP Retransmission] 55635 > microsoft-ds [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0
436.553750   10.63.3.39 -> 10.42.3.203  NBNS 92 Name query NBSTAT *<00><00><00><00><00><00><00><00><00><00><00><00>
436.554051  10.42.3.203 -> 10.63.3.39   NBNS 217 Name query response NBSTAT
436.603070   10.63.3.39 -> 10.42.3.203  TCP 66 55690 > netbios-ssn [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1398 WS=256 SACK_
439.614949   10.63.3.39 -> 10.42.3.203  TCP 66 [TCP Retransmission] 55690 > netbios-ssn [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0
445.600591   10.63.3.39 -> 10.42.3.203  TCP 62 [TCP Retransmission] 55690 > netbios-ssn [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0
457.620875   10.63.3.39 -> 10.42.3.203  TCP 66 55734 > http [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1398 WS=4 SACK_PERM=1
457.621149  10.42.3.203 -> 10.63.3.39   TCP 60 http > 55734 [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=0 Len=0
458.159020   10.63.3.39 -> 10.42.3.203  TCP 66 [TCP Port numbers reused] 55734 > http [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MS
458.159258  10.42.3.203 -> 10.63.3.39   TCP 60 http > 55734 [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=0 Len=0
458.689704   10.63.3.39 -> 10.42.3.203  TCP 62 [TCP Port numbers reused] 55734 > http [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MS
458.690002  10.42.3.203 -> 10.63.3.39   TCP 60 http > 55734 [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=0 Len=0
458.725494   10.63.3.39 -> 10.42.3.203  TCP 66 55736 > http [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1398 WS=4 SACK_PERM=1
458.725696  10.42.3.203 -> 10.63.3.39   TCP 60 http > 55736 [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=0 Len=0
459.260930   10.63.3.39 -> 10.42.3.203  TCP 66 [TCP Port numbers reused] 55736 > http [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MS
459.261180  10.42.3.203 -> 10.63.3.39   TCP 60 http > 55736 [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=0 Len=0
459.795362   10.63.3.39 -> 10.42.3.203  TCP 62 [TCP Port numbers reused] 55736 > http [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MS
459.795640  10.42.3.203 -> 10.63.3.39   TCP 60 http > 55736 [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=0 Len=0
```

It just seems to ignore the packets until the NBNS query to which it responds, and then it alternately ignores or RSTs any other packets.

It also does this fun thing where ping works one way, but not the other:

```
 29.683073  10.42.3.203 -> 10.63.3.39   ICMP 74 Echo (ping) request  id=0x0001, seq=36/9216, ttl=128
 29.688421   10.63.3.39 -> 10.42.3.203  ICMP 74 Echo (ping) reply    id=0x0001, seq=36/9216, ttl=128
 30.758418  10.42.3.203 -> 10.63.3.39   ICMP 74 Echo (ping) request  id=0x0001, seq=37/9472, ttl=128
 30.764715   10.63.3.39 -> 10.42.3.203  ICMP 74 Echo (ping) reply    id=0x0001, seq=37/9472, ttl=128
 31.759546  10.42.3.203 -> 10.63.3.39   ICMP 74 Echo (ping) request  id=0x0001, seq=38/9728, ttl=128
 31.764583   10.63.3.39 -> 10.42.3.203  ICMP 74 Echo (ping) reply    id=0x0001, seq=38/9728, ttl=128
 32.760653  10.42.3.203 -> 10.63.3.39   ICMP 74 Echo (ping) request  id=0x0001, seq=39/9984, ttl=128
 32.766173   10.63.3.39 -> 10.42.3.203  ICMP 74 Echo (ping) reply    id=0x0001, seq=39/9984, ttl=128
 45.221105   10.63.3.39 -> 10.42.3.203  ICMP 74 Echo (ping) request  id=0x0001, seq=4217/30992, ttl=128
 49.749227   10.63.3.39 -> 10.42.3.203  ICMP 74 Echo (ping) request  id=0x0001, seq=4218/31248, ttl=128
 54.747578   10.63.3.39 -> 10.42.3.203  ICMP 74 Echo (ping) request  id=0x0001, seq=4219/31504, ttl=128
 59.754256   10.63.3.39 -> 10.42.3.203  ICMP 74 Echo (ping) request  id=0x0001, seq=4220/31760, ttl=128
```

Windows firewall is not enabled on the machine, and all machines within HQ can access it just fine. There is a Samba server elsewhere in the network that also works just fine from all offices. It's like these Windows machines are simply refusing traffic from things that are not on their subnet.

Disclaimer: I did not choose either the subnetting or to run a fileshare on a Windows 7 box. They are both before my time and I can't change it at this time. I know they are dumb/bad respectively, please try to look past them. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you **sure** Windows Firewall (and all other firewalls if any) are configured correctly? You say it's off, however that's a pretty bad idea in itself. To confirm it's appropriately off for *all* interfaces, can you please post a screenshot of the Windows Firewall control panel screen from the Win 7 PC.

Windows Firewall by default will blockfile-sharing requests from outside the local subnet (and ping is considered a file-sharing protocol...), and your issue sounds exactly like either this, or a routing issue (but the pings working the other way round suggests this isn't likely).

The existence of the subnet-only setting, as well as how to change it, is not particularly obvious in Windows Firewall settings. You have to go to Advanced Settings via the control panel, or by directly running wf.msc, and ensure all Inbound File and Printer Sharing rules, under the Scope tab, are not limited to "Local subnet".

Comment: You win the prize. While I *was* properly checking that Windows firewall was disabled, I was completely ignoring Kaspersky's firewall. Turns out there are some 'Trusted Network' settings in Security Center that I've been ignorant of for the past two years. `:I`